# NS_ENUM as property in protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I came across to strange behaviour. I used to have:

`@property (nonatomic) ApplicationState applicationState;`

directly in my Application class. Now it's extracted to protocol

```
@protocol ApplicationProtocol <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic) ApplicationState applicationState;
```

ApplicationState is Enum

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ApplicationState)
{
    ApplicationStateNormal = 0,
    ApplicationStateExpanded = 1, 
    ApplicationStateMaximized = 2
};
```

Now. It used to work. Now such line:
`self.applicationState = ApplicationStateMaximized;`
called from implementing class causes no effect.

---

**UPDATE**

[Agy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4809376/agy), [rickster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957768/rickster) you're both right. I forgot add to this question note, that I have already synthesized properties in implementing class. What I haven't notice, that my colleague added getter which returned always the same value (unfortunatelly IDE deosn't show this accessor until I duplicated property in my class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needs to synthesize the property:

```
@implementation Application

@synthesize applicationState = _ applicationState;

@end
```

or declare the property again:

```
@interface Application : NSObject <ApplicationProtocol>

@property (nonatomic) ApplicationState applicationState;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a `@property` in a protocol doesn't synthesize storage or accessors for that property in classes that adopt the protocol. For that, you'll want something like this:

```
@implementation Application
@synthesize applicationState = _applicationState;
```